# Creating a new worksheet for each row, but duplicates should be in same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a new worksheet for every customer in my excel file. The customer number is given in column c, but it is only the first 7 letters that shows the customer number. Therefore I would like if the code named each new worksheet it creates, after the customer number, so that it can check if a customer already has a worksheet, and if it does, the next row in the first worksheet that contains the same customer number should be put into that new worksheet, below what has already been copied into there.

```
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
On Error Resume Next
SheetExists = Not InWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Function

```
Sub RowToSheet()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet 1"
With ActiveSheet
    xRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To xRow
         If Not SheetExists(Left(Cells(I, 3), 7)) Then Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = Left(Cells(I, 3), 7)
        .Rows(I).Copy Sheets(Left(Cells(I, 3), 7)).Cells(Sheets(Left(Cells(I, 3), 7)).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
        Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(Left(Cells(I, 3), 7)).Rows(1)
    Next I
End With
```

[image: Rest of code]

[image: First worksheet]

Comment: Just copy and paste all your code from the VBE. The best way is to get a list of unique items, loop throught them, filter each and copy the filtered range to a new sheet.

Comment: Your Customer number include a colon which is not valid in a sheet name, would just the 5 digits be OK ? or do you want to just remove it to give a 6 digits eg C00565

Comment: Ahh okay, yes the 5 digits after the colon would be just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary to hold the unique customer numbers. Loop through them applying a filter to column C and copy the filtered records to a new sheet/workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RowToSheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Integer

    Dim dict As Object, key, rng As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet 1")
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:P" & LastRow)

    ' build list of unique values from col C
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        key = Trim(Left(ws.Cells(i, "C"), 7))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then dict(key) = 1
    Next

    ' delete any existing sheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each wsNew In wb.Sheets
       If wsNew.Name <> "Sheet 1" Then
            wsNew.Delete
       End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    n = wb.Sheets.Count

    ' create new sheets/workbooks for each unique value
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each key In dict.keys

        Set wsNew = wb.Sheets.Add(after:=wb.Sheets(n))
        wsNew.Name = Right(key, 5) ' number with  C:
        n = n + 1

        ' filter on col C and copy to new sheet
        rng.AutoFilter 3, Criteria1:=CStr(key) & "*"
        rng.Copy wsNew.Range("A1")
        rng.AutoFilter 3

        ' copy to new workbook
        wsNew.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs wb.Path & "\" & wsNew.Name
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    MsgBox dict.Count & " workbooks created", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Test if the sheet exists before adding a new one. Here's a simple function for checking if a sheet with that name exists:

```vb
Function SheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional InWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If InWorkbook Is Nothing Then Set InWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    SheetExists = Not InWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You would add it to your code like:

```vb
Sub RowToSheet()
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet 1"
    With ActiveSheet
        xRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For I = 2 To xRow
            If Not SheetExists("Row " & I) Then Worksheets.Add(, Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Row " & I
            .Rows(I).Copy Sheets("Row " & I).Range("A2")
            Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(I).Rows(1)
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

This way the sheet is only created if it did not already exist. The `.Copy` will overwrite the values on `Range("A2")` so you will want to change that to dynamically search for the next empty row like:

```vb
.Rows(I).Copy Sheets("Row " & I).Cells(Sheets("Row " & I).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
```

And your line `Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets(I).Rows(1)` is just guessing that the new sheet will be in the same position as the loop index. I suggest correcting that to be:

```vb
Sheets(1).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Row " & I).Rows(1)
```

Comment: I answered based on my understanding of your question but I am not sure I understood how there will be duplicate names or what the conditions are for combining values onto the output sheets. If you could provide more clarity on those topics, I will edit my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: Thank you @toddleson, It was really helpfull. I just updated the post so it is more clear what I meant with duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You need Ron de Bruin's new sheet for all unique values!

```
Sub Copy_To_Worksheets()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Add a worksheet to copy the a unique list and add the CriteriaRange
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add a new worksheet
                Set WSNew = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Name = cell.Value
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1
                    WSNew.Name = "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000")
                    Err.Clear
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                'Copy the visible data to the new worksheet
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With
            End If

            'Show all data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell

        'Delete the ws2 sheet
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source:

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_4.htm